# How to install ML-Agents on M3 Mac: Onnx & Protobuf Issues

Tags: git, macos, unity-game-engine, machine-learning, onnx

I'm trying to install ML-Agents on my M3 Mac using conda. I was following the instructions listed in the web docs (https://unity-technologies.github.io/ml-agents/Installation/), but I ran into an issue with the protobuf version. I changed it to 3.6, but that doesn't work with onnx which seems to require 4.25. I'm really unsure of how to fix this and I would appreciate any help!

Here are the commands I ran to get to this point:

1. conda create -n mlagents python=3.10.12 && conda activate mlagents
2. git clone --branch release_21 https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents.git
3. python -m pip install ./ml-agents-envs (worked)
4. python -m pip install ./ml-agents